# How to backup a mysql database stored on an external storage device?

Tags: mysql

I had a WAMP server installed on a hard drive that crashed. I recovered most of the data onto an external storage device, but I don't know how to get my recovered mysql databases off of the recovery drive and onto the new computer running the new WAMP server.

Can I just locate the database files in the old /wamp64 directory and copy them?

Comment: if it is complete yes that will go, if parts are missing you must try to recover it. and make the nexet time regularly a backup

Comment: Yes, I won't make that mistake again!

I don't suppose you know where in the wamp64 folder I can find those files?

Comment: somewgere in the wamp folder you will find a my.ini there you find all the used folders